# react-native: How do I install the pod dependencies used by the library in my current project?

Tags: react-native

I'm making a simple React Native library.
It has dependency on other library([react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info)) that use native module.

[image: Library dependencies image]

And also i'm making a React Native project to test the library.
However, when this is executed, an error occurs saying there is no native module(react-native-device-info).

[image: Error Image]

Of course i ran "pod install" in ios directory.
And if i install 'react-native-device-info' library in the project, it doesn't make the error.

So i consider to add 'react-native-device-info' library as peerDependencies, But I want developers who use my library to use it without any extra installation.

Do i need to do something on my library?

[Version]

- react-native: 0.70.6
- My library only has typescript files not ios and android folder.
- I built the library only with tsc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think bringing RN 3rd dependencies with your library is a good idea because of possible conflicts. Imagine a situation when your lib user will previously have its own version of device-info? With `peerDependencies` you can control which versions are compatible with your library but with particular dependency, you have to force the user you use your version of `device-info`.

For example this library https://github.com/rodgomesc/vision-camera-code-scanner has a dependency to `vision-camera` but it doesn't bring it and only keeps it in `devDependencies`